# Get Value of a colum from GridView Windows Mobile 6.0

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-mobile

Somebody please tell me how to get the value of the first column of the selected row of gridview in windows mobile application 6.0 (Emulator is standard). I used to get this value from the windows application by using the code shown below but this is not working in windows mobile 6.0 standard verstion

```
dgridShipmentItemTypes.Rows[nIndex].Cells["dgridShmtItmTypeName"].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int rowIndex = dgridShipmentItemTypes.CurrentCell.RowNumber;
int nIndex = 0; // Whatever your column index is.
object obj = dgridShipmentItemTypes[rowIndex, nIndex];
if ((obj != null) && (obj != DBNull.Value)) {
  // do something with it
}
```